# Link Only Answers rejected by moderator

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderation, link-only-answers

I marked 2 answers to this question, [Where Should I Store a database Connection String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177060/where-should-i-store-a-database-connection-string/4177110#4177110)
(including the accepted answer) as 'link only' answers (which they clearly are).

A moderator has declined them with the attached comment "declined - a moderator 
reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

This is not in keeping with other responses here: [New policy on Link-Only Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144566/new-policy-on-link-only-answers)

Nor is it in keeping with old answers (pre 2010) I've had removed due to being link only answers.

This moderator inconsistency is not good.

Comment: The more recent guidelines on NAA and link-only answers is [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/369403). Reading that should explain why they're declined

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very good question in the first place.  It wouldn't surprise me to see it being closed and deleted in short order.

Comment: @MitchWheat Because it has an answer with upvotes. Did you miss that? I guess so, looking at your rep.

Comment: @MitchWheat since you haven't asked questions on Meta, you may not be aware that downvotes here are not harmful; they often show disagreement or are an indication that you've asked a question that's already commonly asked.

Comment: Vandalizing your post is not going to get it deleted. It will get your post locked so you cannot edit it, might get you a "cool-down" suspension if the mods feel it's warranted, but it will not get your post deleted. There is nothing wrong with your post remaining on the site. It is a signpost to another useful post.

Comment: any post I write is copyright 'me'; it's a GDPR guarantee. If I decide to delete it, that's my right.

Comment: I suggest you check out the [terms of service and privacy policy.](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) You can certainly request disassociation to have your information removed from it, but by posting to Stack Overflow, you have given them rights to continue to display the post through the CC-BY-SA license.

Comment: terms of service do not nullify one's statutory rights.

Comment: You still own the copyright but by posting you gave SE a license to publish the content you posted. And we don't think *deleted ....................* is the version we like best, so we prefer the revision posted first.

Comment: well, I prefer to delete it. As is my right.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but I beg to differ if that is your right. You can take it to arbitration if you like. Unless you opted-out .. in which case you can sue them ...

Comment: @rene: are you speaking for SO?

Comment: @rene Don't waste your time. If they feel they have the absolute right to remove the content they licensed to SO, they'll have to take it to a lawyer. Nothing we say is going to convince them that they have licensed the content, and SO has the right to keep it on the site even if they have to remove the user's personal information from the post.

Comment: No, I'm not speaking for SO. I'm only trying to give my interpretation of the ToS to help you make the right choices.

Comment: Mitch, you're welcome to email us if you'd like to discuss it. I'm not deleting this as doing so would make it an even _more_ colossal waste of time for all involved. I'm happy to disassociate it from your account and purge all comments, but you need to contact us to make that happen.

Answer (score 11):

That post is *an answer to the question* that also happens to contain a link for further information.  It's not just a link that doesn't actually attempt to answer the question.  You can read your own links to discussions on what types of posts are and are not actually answers for more details and specifics.

If you feel that the answer given is not a good answer, you're free to downvote it accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the rather pedantic downvote advice. I'm well aware of how to downvote.

Comment: @MitchWheat So then you just think that the answer that you linked to is actually a useful answer?  Interesting, given that you're trying to have it deleted.

Comment: you're making assumptions.

Comment: @MitchWheat What assumption do you think I'm making that I shouldn't be, and why do you feel that assumption isn't appropriate?

Comment: nevermind. I'm not going to get sucked into your trolling.

Comment: Odd that you think asking someone to explain their accusation is trolling, and yet making an accusation and refusing to explain it isn't.

Comment: @Mitch Servy's way is definitely curt, and oftentimes pedantic... but there is no trolling on their part there. The advice given is very valid, and they are just trying to understand why you disagree with it.... Not answering will not do anything.... anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Removing the link markup from the flagged answers gives the following:

> You could store connections strings in the configuration file. You may secure them if necessary.

and

> Store it on your App.config file and always encrypt it. This link will show you how to encrypt parts of your configuration file.

Even if the links go down, the remaining content in those answers is still viable. Per [Shog9's classic post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), this fits under the section "And all those other answers with links in them".

Both seem to me to be answers, both were upvoted, and one was accepted, so I don't see how it would make the site a better place to remove them. I would have declined these flags, too.